# Event based de-duplication and prioritisation software

Tags: data-structure

We have an **event processing system** that is struggling to meet **throughput requirements.** The problem is that we need to handle **out of order messages**, by **reprocessing each affected event after that point**. We have implemented optimistic concurrency so that we can scale our processing algorithm, however when we tried to use it, we were getting some issues that were dragging down the throughput

1. OCC conflicts would **go to the back of the queue**, causing any affecting event already in the queue to require 'immediate' reprocessing (i.e. given the *set* of affecting messages in the queue, there's no point processing the head of the queue, given messages already in it)
2. When selecting subsequent events for reprocessing, these can over-lap and the **same messages can be entered into the queue multiple times**

We would therefore like to include some **intermediary software that can prioritise and deduplicate the messages**.

We looked at RabbitMQ first, as it's known to us, and found that it has a deduplication plugin but that its prioritisation is limited to 255 groups of priorities, which would help but not eliminate unnecessary reprocessing. So are interested to hear about alternative message queues, event processing frameworks/platforms, etc.

We are happy to host our own instance, or use a managed system someone else is hosting.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: I think you are looking for FIFO queues, you could try AWSs SQS and configure visibility timeout and dead letter queues. RabbitMQ is popular but it's not the best, plus one cause surely there is something out there, SQS you can use from on-prem with api-gateway directly or a direct connect link, eg: https://lumigo.io/blog/the-why-when-and-how-of-api-gateway-service-proxies/

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The queue needs to be _prioritised_ by the time of the event, as they can be re-added at a later time. If added FIFO at this point, the queue can become disordered resulting in more re-processing than necessary.